# Apply layout for pages accessed via site.pages.content

Tags: jekyll

I’m trying to render specific md file inside of html using code:

```
{% assign subheader = site.pages | where: "title", "subheader" | first %}

{{ subheader.content }}
```

It works, but my layout isn’t respected. Does it work as expected? Is there a way to apply this layout?

Comment: What do you mean by *"my layout isn’t respected"*? Please elaborate..

Comment: @ashmaroli, I have a layout called `subheader` in my _layouts folder, which is not used while displaying this object

Comment: Why don't you use includes ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel, can I include `*.md` file?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267113/using-jekyll-how-to-organize-place-paragraph-data-within-layout-that-is-not-pos/49275366#49275366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layouts are applied in context to the "current page".

In your example, if `{{ subheader.content }}` has been inserted into say, **`base.md`** that defines a **`layout: base`** in the front matter, then `{{ subheader.content }}` is rendered **as part of "`base.md`"** and will therefore be a part of *its* layout (`_layouts/base.html`).

There is no out-of-the-box way to render individual sections of a page rendered with multiple layouts.

The only possible route is to *inherit* another layout.

For example,
say I have a "base" layout with following:

```
[...]
<header>
  <div id="parent-element">
    <div class="btn">foo</div>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
</header>
[...]
```

and another layout `subheader`:

```
---
layout: base
---

<ul id="greek">
  <li><a href="#">alpha</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">beta</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">gamma</a></li>
</ul>
{{ content }}
```

and finally a "page.md" that *uses* the subheader layout:

```
---
layout: subheader
---

<ul id="fruits">
  <li><a href="#">apples</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">oranges</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bananas</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then, the generated "page.html" will be:

```
[...]
<header>
  <div id="parent-element">
    <div class="btn">foo</div>
    <ul id="greek">
      <li><a href="#">alpha</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">beta</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">gamma</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="fruits">
      <li><a href="#">apples</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">oranges</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">bananas</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
[...]
```

Comment: just to clarify, I want to create a separate layout for part of a page. with your approach I don't understand how I can do this

Comment: I did add a clarification regarding that.. In case you missed it, let me rephrase: **There is no way, out-of-the-box, *to render individual sections of a page* with separate layouts.**